# Now which widgets are right now shown in List

Tags: flutter, dart

Hello I have a ListView with different Widgets of different height. Now I want to know which of those Widgets are at the moment visible in the ListView. Does anyone has an idea how to do it. I can't use to scroll_to_widget package because it interferes other implementations.

Answer (score 0):

Try using https://pub.dev/packages/visibility_detector maybe you can create a separate list and store `true` according to index, based on their visibility?